Do pilots have to produce their pilot license to police when asked?
if an airport police officer asks to see the pilot's
license of a private aircraft pilot, does that pilot have to show it?

Legally (as in that they can be arrested for failure to do so) or by regulation (as in they can lose their license for failure to do so)?

In short, yes, although this is in practice very rare and most likely to be the FAA or an NTSB official first (after something has gone wrong) rather than a police officer.
The pilot's license (or certificate in FAA parlance) is just one of several documents that may be requested, depending upon the pilot and what they are doing.
In the US, this comes under FAA regulations; Title 14, Chapter 1, Subchapter D, Part 61, Subpart A, Section 61.51, paragraph (i) of which (!) reads:

Presentation of required documents.
(1) Persons must present their pilot certificate, medical certificate,
logbook, or any other record required by this part for inspection upon
a reasonable request by—
(i) The Administrator [i.e. of the FAA];
(ii) An authorized representative from the National Transportation
Safety Board; or
(iii) Any Federal, State, or local law enforcement officer.
(2) A student pilot must carry the following items in the aircraft on
all solo cross-country flights as evidence of the required authorized
instructor clearances and endorsements—
(i) Pilot logbook;
(ii) Student pilot certificate; and
(iii) Any other record required by this section.
(3) A sport pilot must carry his or her logbook or other evidence of
required authorized instructor endorsements on all flights.
(4) A recreational pilot must carry his or her logbook with the
required authorized instructor endorsements on all solo flights—
(i) That exceed 50 nautical miles from the airport at which training
was received;
(ii) Within airspace that requires communication with air traffic
control;
(iii) Conducted between sunset and sunrise; or
(iv) In an aircraft for which the pilot does not hold an appropriate
category or class rating.
(5) A flight instructor with a sport pilot rating must carry his or
her logbook or other evidence of required authorized instructor
endorsements on all flights when providing flight training.

